# Blazor StateHasChanged() method not working with SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side

I need to listen to a method in signalR and update the UI when this happens. Data is coming but UI is not updating

here is my code:

```cs
@foreach (var user in users)
{
    <MudItem xs="12" md="6">
            <MudCard>
                    <h3>@user.FirstName @user.LastName</h3>
            </MudCard>
    </MudItem>
}


@code {
 List<UserDto> users = new();

 HubConnection connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("ws://localhost:6172/chat")
    .Build();

 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
    connection.On<UserDto>("UserJoined", async (user) =>
    {
        users.Add(user);
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    });

    await connection.StartAsync();
 }
}
```

If I try to use the StateHasChanged() method like below I get an exception:

```cs
connection.On<UserDto>("UserJoined", async (user) =>
    {
        users.Add(user);
        StateHasChanged();
    });
```

Exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.'
```

Comment: A simple search on the error would have provided an answer and also pointed you to at least one answer on here.  See also  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/synchronization-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#invoke-component-methods-externally-to-update-state

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - that dupe only applies to the last part of the question. The part that is irrelevant.

Comment: @NodirbekAbdulaxadov - ask a more precise question. The part with the exception does not seem relevant. The first part should have worked, that is more interesting.  Any errors in the console or output window?

Comment: And do specify the RenderMode (interactivity). It could be just [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78170115/60761)

Comment: In any case, `users.Add(user);` is another time-bomb waiting to go off. You will have to make this thread-safe.

Comment: I reopened the question as you're almost certainly right.

Comment: WoW! Thanks for your answer, @HenkHolterman. I spent so many hours trying to solve this, but a single line of code `@rendermode InteractiveServer` solved the problem!

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - and closed again. Your template q+a for Blazor 8 wasn't welcome but we just need a 'canonical' for this case. If you have better suggestions then add them to the dupes here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Agree totally.  MS didn't imagine the chaos they would cause with that stupid template: *Per Page/Component* is a honey pot the unwary seem unable to resist.  I'll sleep on how to phrase the question to not trigger the SO community immune system.