TryParseValueFromString not triggered - no validation message output
Based on the Blazor University tutorials and many SO/GitHub posts I am trying to create a custom component that inherits from InputBase<int?>.
It displays fine, but on submission the custom validation method TryParseValueFromString() does not fire and so my validation messages are not bubbling up into the edit context, nor displaying:

Setting a breakpoint in the method body further proves the method is never triggering as the breakpoint is never hit.
In time this will have complex validation, so I cannot rely on DataAnnotations validation to provide these checks and want to better understand TryParseValueFromString().
Can somebody please advise how to get the above method to trigger for a non-parseable value?
Page code
@page "/"
@using BlazorAppTryParseValueFromString.Component
@using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.RenderMode
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm Model="myModel" OnValidSubmit="FormSubmit">
    
    <ValidationSummary />

    <p>
        <IntegerComponent @bind-Value=myModel.MyNumber />
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
        <ValidationMessage For="() => myModel.MyNumber" />
    </p>

    <p>
        @Result
    </p>

</EditForm>

@code {
    public class MyModel
    {
        public int? MyNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public string Result { get; set; } = "";

    public MyModel myModel { get; set; } = new();

    public async void FormSubmit()
    {
        string yourNumber = myModel.MyNumber.HasValue ? myModel.MyNumber.Value.ToString() : "nothing";
        Result = $"Your number was {yourNumber}";
    }
}

Component code
@inherits InputBase<int?>

<div>
    <input type="text" @bind=CurrentValue />
</div>

@code {
    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, out int? result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        validationErrorMessage = "";
        result = null;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            return true;
        }

        int parsedInt;

        if (!int.TryParse(value.Trim(), out parsedInt))
        {
            validationErrorMessage = "Invalid value!";
            return false;
        }

        result = parsedInt;
        return true;
    }
}

Updates

Added the tutorial file from Blazor University to my project, and that same method doesn't get triggered there either.  This would appear to be a wider-scale issue therefore.
Created a new Blazor Server project type (native .Net8) in VS2022 and added the same page. Same failure occurs.


You tagged .net8, so what is your Interactivity (rendermode) here?

Still insufficient info. What mode is your component using? The default is Static.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78171080/60761  . Add it to the page with the form.

I get, 'The name 'InteractiveServer' does not exist in the current context'

Hi @EvilDr, For 'The name 'InteractiveServer' does not exist in the current context'. be sure add @using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.RenderMode.

Thanks @Rena.  RenderMode now set but the problem persists exactly as before.  All input welcome!

I was incorrectly binding to the CurrentValue rather than CurrentValueAsString.  I'm assuming that because a user always enters a string (regardless of what it actually looks like), the TryParseValueFromString then triggers against that string to validate and translate into the desired bound value's type.
<input type="text" @bind=CurrentValue />

Should be
<input type="text" @bind=CurrentValueAsString />

Or with the correct HTML5 input for more automated validation:
<input type="number" @bind=CurrentValueAsString />

