How can I periodically refresh data on a Blazor - Server Side page from an API?
I have a single page on a Blazor App that I'm looking to have refresh the data every so often.
The timer works, I can set a breakpoint and see that the data is updating, but the InvokeAsync calls to notify that StateHasChanged appear to do nothing.
Every second I see the API call to the front end, I see that _horses contains the updated data afterwards.
@page "/"
@using DerbyStonks.Blazor.Services.Derby.Entities
@using System.Timers
@inject IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<br/>

<h1>Horses</h1>

@if (_loading)
{
    <h3>Loading ...</h3>
}
else
{
    <ul class="horse-list">
        @foreach (Horse horse in _horses)
        {
            <li class="horse-list-item">
                <h2>#@horse.Number: @horse.Name</h2>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}

@code
{
    Timer _timer;
    bool _loading = true;
    List<Horse> _horses = new List<Horse>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await LoadHorses();
        StartHotReload();
    }

    private void StartHotReload()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(1000); // 1 second interval
        _timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await LoadHorsesAndUpdateUI();
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private async Task LoadHorsesAndUpdateUI()
    {
        try
        {
            await LoadHorses();
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exception (e.g., log, display error message)
        }
    }

    private async Task LoadHorses()
    {
        HttpClient client = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(NavigationManager.BaseUri);

        _loading = true;
        try
        {
            var horses = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Horse>>("api/Horses");
            if (horses != null)
            {
                _horses = horses;
            }
            else
            {
                _horses.Clear(); // Clear the list if no horses are returned
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _loading = false;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}



I've been at this for a day or so, I've tried a number of unsuccessful permutations on this problem.

If I call StateHasChanged directly, it doesn't have access to the dispatcher.
If I make the timer non-static, it gets disposed almost immediately and does nothing
I've consulted a number of sources trying to hunt this down

Values does not refresh in a Blazor view from async call
https://www.reddit.com/r/Blazor/comments/1aw6uvc/reload_not_applied_despite_statehaschanged_call/


I've consulted ChatGPT and permutated on solutions/changes offered by it.


"If I make the timer non-static, it gets disposed almost immediately" - is weird. State your Blazor version and for 8+ state the Interactivity. Check if this workd: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78171080/60761

And btw: there is no static in the code.

Apologies, at several points there was.
I see you referencing a solution that suggests adding this @rendermode InteractiveServer
I'm curious because @rendermode doesn't seem to be recognized by Visual Studio. But it also Seems to work.

I've taken your code and replaced the API call with a mock.
The code works as I would expect.  It updates when the timer expires.
@page "/"
@using System.Timers
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<br />

<h1>Horses</h1>

@if (_loading)
{
    <h3>Loading ...</h3>
}
else
{
    <ul class="horse-list">
        @foreach (Horse horse in _horses)
        {
            <li class="horse-list-item">
                <h2>#@horse.Number: @horse.Name</h2>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}

@code
{
    Timer _timer;
    bool _loading = true;
    List<Horse> _horses = new List<Horse>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await LoadHorses();
        StartHotReload();
    }

    private void StartHotReload()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(1000); // 1 second interval
        _timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await LoadHorsesAndUpdateUI();
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private async Task LoadHorsesAndUpdateUI()
    {
        try
        {
            await LoadHorses();
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exception (e.g., log, display error message)
        }
    }

    private async Task LoadHorses()
    {

        _loading = true;
        try
        {
            var horses = await this.GetHorsesAsync();
            if (horses != null)
            {
                _horses = horses.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                _horses.Clear(); // Clear the list if no horses are returned
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _loading = false;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }

    public class Horse
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }

    private int counter = 0;

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Horse>> GetHorsesAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(index => new Horse
            {
                Number = index,
                Name = $"Demo {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}",
            });
    }
}

For your reference:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SO78362385.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

And
using SO78362385.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();


Is there something you've done with respect to the RenderMode?
I tried adding @rendermode InteractiveServer and it seems to work, but also I believe that the app was set up with interactive server mode.

In Program.CS I have the following lines
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();
and
app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

Deployed as Interactive Server with Global Interactivity.
