My CustomInput does not work in Blazor wasm
First, this is my customInputText component:
@inherits InputBase<string>

@inject CustomValidatorService CustomValidatorService;

<input class="@ClassCss" placeholder="@PlaceHolder"  
       @oninput="@HandleOnInput" @onchange="@HandleOnChange" 
       type="text" required="@IsRequired"/>

<CustomValidatorMessenger ValidationMessage="@_validateMessage"/>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? ClassCss { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? PlaceHolder { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? FieldToValidate { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnChange { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool IsRequired { get; set; } = true;

    private string? _validateMessage;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FieldToValidate);
    }

    private void Validate()
    {
        var validateResult = CustomValidatorService.Validate(this, FieldToValidate ?? nameof(Value));

        var validationResults = validateResult.ToList();

        if (validationResults.Any())
        {
            _validateMessage = validationResults.First().ErrorMessage;
        }
    }

    private void HandleOnInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Value = e.Value?.ToString();
        ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
        Validate();
    }

    private async Task HandleOnChange()
    {
        if (OnChange.HasDelegate)
        {
            await OnChange.InvokeAsync();
        }
    }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out string result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string? validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = value;
        validationErrorMessage = _validateMessage;
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationErrorMessage);
    }

}

And my CustomValidatorService:
public class CustomValidatorService
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(object model, string? propertyName = default)
    {
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var context = new ValidationContext(model);

        if (propertyName is null)
        {
            Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, validationResults, true);

            return validationResults;
        }

        var property = model.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

        if (property is null)
        {
            return validationResults;
        }

        property.GetValue(model);

        context.MemberName = property.Name;

        return validationResults;
    }
}

And this is how I use it:
<EditForm Model="RegisterModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator/>

    <div class="mb-4 flex justify-between">
        <CustomInputText bind-Value="@FirstName" PlaceHolder="First Name"
               ValueExpression="@(() => FirstName)"
               ClassCss="form-control mt-1 block w-[48%] px-6 py-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
               OnChange="HandleUsernameInput" 
               FieldToValidate="@(nameof(RegisterModel.Username))"/>

        <CustomInputText bind-Value="@LastName" PlaceHolder="Last Name"
               ValueExpression="@(() => FirstName)"
               ClassCss="form-control mt-1 block w-[48%] px-6 py-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
               OnChange="HandleUsernameInput" 
               FieldToValidate="@nameof(RegisterModel.Username)"/>
    </div>
</EditForm>

The first problem is the input value is passed to the customInput, but the parent is not binding, it's like 1 way binding.
The second problem is that the validate is not working, I have tried console.writeline and it's empty, and I do not know why.
How can I fix or improve it?

Always the 1st check: what is your rendermode? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78171080/60761

I use wasm so it dont have rendermode bro

for validation issue could you please check property name FieldToValidate matches exactly the property name of the model RegisterModel.
